# Batch crop image having variable height

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I want to batch crop images having variable height. I have fixed width, x and y coordinates value but not the height value. I tried the code mentioned below but it didn't work. Only top, left and right side needs to be cropped.

```
mogrify -crop 320xauto+864+323 +repage image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-chop` instead of `-crop`:

```
mogrify -chop 864x0 +repage image.png
mogrify -chop 0x323 +repage image.png
mogrify -gravity East -chop 333x0 +repage image.png
```

Comment: You can put all three commands into one mogrify. Also you should specify the value for the -path variable.